# Overloaded constructor error when creating trigger programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I want to create a process, when person submits a form and I get only filled in information (not every field is required for filling). Found code (http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-docs-email-form/20884/), did everything according to author, but doesn't work me. I'm not a specialist in coding, so I need your help.

Here is the code:

```js
function Initialize() {

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers();

  for(var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendGoogleForm")
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();

}

function SendGoogleForm(e) 
{  
  try 
  {      
    // You may replace this with another email address
    var email = "justbeincredible@gmail.com";

    // Optional but change the following variable
    // to have a custom subject for Google Form email notifications
    var subject = "New Driver Application Arrived";  

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var columns = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
    var message = "";    

    // Only include form fields that are not blank
    for ( var keys in columns ) {
      var key = columns[keys];
      if ( e.namedValues[key] && (e.namedValues[key] != "") ) {
        message += key + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[key] + "\n\n"; 
      }
    }

    // This is the MailApp service of Google Apps Script
    // that sends the email. You can also use GmailApp for HTML Mail.

    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 

  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }

}
```

Here is what I get when I run Initialize to test:

```
Cannot call overloaded constructor forSpreadsheet with parameters
(null) because there is more than one matching constructor signature:
interface SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder forSpreadsheet(Spreadsheet)
interface SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder forSpreadsheet(String) (line 12,
file "Code")
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the code inside the Script Editor of the Google Spreadsheet that is collecting the responses and not inside the Form editor.
[[source](http://ctrlq.org/help/81-google-error-cannot-call-overloaded-constructor-forspreadsheet)]

Explanation: The error message indicates that `forSpreadsheet()` had a parameter of `(null)`. You fed it `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`, so that evaluated to `null`. That method is only applicable within Spreadsheet-bound scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The add-on doesn't work on brave browser. Try running on Google Chrome if you are not currently using it.